# How to use multiple values in "Shortcode"?

Tags: shortcode

I've requirement to use multiple values for Shortcode.

Currently I'm adding 2 separate shortcodes for the same

e.g.

```
[wpcode id="2658"]

[wpdiscuz_comments]
```

Is there a way to use single Shortcode and add multiple values ?

Comment: What problem does doing this solve?  What you've written doesn't make sense, can you describe the original problem? Is there any particular reason not to use 2 shortcodes? I edited out the references to widgets as widgets are not shortcodes, and shortcodes are not widgets.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine these two shortcodes into one by using a custom shortcode that includes both of them:

```
function custom_shortcode() {
    $output = '';

    // Get the wpcode shortcode output
    $wpcode_output = do_shortcode('[wpcode id="2658"]');

    // Get the wpdiscuz_comments shortcode output
    $wpdiscuz_output = do_shortcode('[wpdiscuz_comments]');

    // Combine the two outputs into a single output
    $output .= $wpcode_output . $wpdiscuz_output;

    // Return the combined output
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('custom_shortcode', 'custom_shortcode');
```

Please note: The way to pass values to a shortcode can vary depending on the specific shortcode and the plugin or theme that provides it.